# why iam getting only one output and please tell what should i use to get both the values explain in simplest way

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, put

```
const addingAttribute=async (req,res)=>{
     let data = req.body
let findPublisher=await publisherModel.find({$or:[{name:'Penguin'},{name:' HarperCollin'}]}).select({_id:1})
console.log(findPublisher)
    let updateBook=await bookModel1.updateMany({publisher:arr},{$set:data},
{new:true})
console.log(updateBook)
    res.send({msg:updateBook})
    }
```

For the books published by 'Penguin' and 'HarperCollins', update this key to true.

but this code is updating for only the first value this is bcoz I am a using or can u please tell me anything else

Comment: select({_id:1} will not get only data with column _id = 1 ?

Comment: `this is bcoz`, `or can u`, please try and avoid playground speak, there are lots of people from around the world were English is not there native tongue, and this does not help.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB's `find` returns something called a database cursor. You have to exercise the cursor's API to chase through all the values it is presenting.